# Are there any desktop tool to access Swift Storage?

Tags: openstack-swift

I am in a project using Swift Storage and I want to find some desktop tools that can work well with Swift Storage. The 'Gladinet Destop' may be a good choice, but it doesn't seem very suitable for Swift Storage. (It meets some other Cloud Files Storage quite well.) Does anyone have some recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) can be used to access Swift Storage. It provides a ftp-like interface.

[s3ql](https://code.google.com/p/s3ql/) is a file system that stores data online using storage services. it communicates with Swift very well.